# How do I make this image morphing function function repeat?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Images morph one into another. I want this function to loop infinitely:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cup2").fadeOut(15000);
    $(".cup1").animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 15000);
    $(".cup1").delay(5000).fadeOut(10000);
    $(".cup4").delay(15000).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 15000);
    $(".cup4").delay(5000).fadeOut(6000);
    $(".cup5").delay(30000).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 15000);
    $(".cup5").delay(5000).fadeOut(6000);
    $(".cup6").delay(45000).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 15000);
    $(".cup6").delay(8000).fadeOut(5000);
    $(".cup7").delay(55000).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 15000);
});
```

Comment: Please edit the title of the question.

Comment: First of all, instead of starting all animations at once, but with a delay, you can actually let one animation follow the other by providing a callback that is called after the animation ends. That will also make it easier to just start 'the next' one, and start the first one again if there is no next one.

Answer (score 0):

> try this to iterate

```
  function fader() {
    setInterval(function(){
       $(".cup2").fadeToggle(400);
    }, 1000);
}
setTimeout(fader, 5000);
```

Comment: so how do i add the other images to this??

Answer (score 0):

> use promise rather then delay

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function loop(){
    $(".cup2").fadeOut(4000,function(){
      $(".cup1").animate({opacity:'1'},4000).promise().then(function() {  $(".cup1").fadeOut(10000);
          $(".cup4").animate({opacity:'1'},4000).promise().then(function() {  $(".cup4").fadeOut(10000); 
            $(".cup5").animate({opacity:'1'},4000).promise().then(function() {  $(".cup5").fadeOut(10000); 
              $(".cup6").animate({opacity:'1'},4000).promise().then(function() {  $(".cup6").fadeOut(10000); 
                $(".cup7").animate({opacity:'1'},4000).promise().then(function() {  $(".cup7").fadeOut(10000); 
                    $(".cup2").animate({opacity:'1'},4000).promise().then(function() { loop(); });
                });
              });
            });
          });
      });  
    });
  }
  loop();
});
```